# PHP Short-Circuit Evaluation (Good/Bad?)

Tags: php, short-circuiting

This is a general question of sorts, but to explain it I will use a specific example.

I have a function that loads a document. If that document does not exist it will create it, if it does exist it will convert it to a JSON array. I always want this function to return an array of some sort, whether or not there is an issue with `json_decode()` or if the file does not exist. Currently I am doing it like so...

```
function load($file) {
    if( ! file_exists($file)) {
        $handle = fopen($file, 'w');
        fclose($handle);
    }

    $raw = file_get_contents($file);
    $contents = json_decode($raw, TRUE);

    return( ! $contents ? array() : $contents);
    //cant use ternary shorthand "?:" in PHP 5.2, otherwise this would be shorter
}
```

Now, there is nothing wrong with the above code (at least I don't think there is and it works fine). However I'm always looking for ways to improve my code and condense it while keeping it perfectly legible. And that return statement has always bothered me because of how inefficient it seems. So today I got to thinking and something occurred to me. I remember seeing mysql tutorials that do something to the effect of `connect() or die();` so I thought, why not `json_decode() or array();`? Would this even work? So I rewrote my function to find out...

```
function load($file) {
    if( ! file_exists($file)) {
        $handle = fopen($file, 'w');
        fclose($handle);
    }

    $raw = file_get_contents($file);
    return json_decode($raw, TRUE) or array();
}
```

It seems to, and it even reads pleasantly enough. So on to my next bout of questions. Is this good practice? I understand it, but would anyone else? Does it really work or is this some bug with a happy ending? I got to looking around and found out that what I'm asking about is called short-circuit evaluation and not a bug. That was good to know. I used that new term to refine my search and came up with some more material.

[Blog Entry](http://www.johnciacia.com/2010/10/18/short-circuit-evaluation-in-php/)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

There wasn't much and most everything I found that talked about using short-circuiting in the way I'm inquiring about always referred to MySQL connections. Now, I know most people are against using the `or die()` terminology, but only because it is an inelegant way to deal with errors. This isn't a problem for the method I'm asking about because I'm not seeking to use `or die()`. Is there any other reason not to use this? Wikipedia seems to think so, but only in reference to C. I know PHP is written in C, so that is definitely pertinent information. But has this issue been wheedled out in the PHP compilation? If not, is it as bad as Wikipedia makes it out to be?

Here's the snippet from Wikipedia.

**Wikipedia** - "Short-circuiting can lead to errors in branch prediction on modern processors, and dramatically reduce performance (a notable example is highly optimized ray with axis aligned box intersection code in ray tracing)[clarification needed]. Some compilers can detect such cases and emit faster code, but it is not always possible due to possible violations of the C standard. Highly optimized code should use other ways for doing this (like manual usage of assembly code)"

What do you all think?

**EDIT**

I've polled another forum and gotten some good results there. General consensus appears to be that this form of variable assignment, while valid, is not preferred, and may even be considered bad form in the real world. I'll continue to keep an ear to the ground and will update this if anything new comes around. Thank you Corbin and Matt for your input, especially Corbin for clearing up a few things. [Here](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/php-short-circuit-evaluation-good-bad-904285.html)'s a link to the forum post should you be interested.

Comment: @DaveRandom typical answer from someone who is against php

Comment: In your original return statement, why bake-in the negative? `return   $contents ? $contents : array();`.  No need for the parens either.

Comment: @Madbreaks: That was actually from a previous condition that I removed. It originally looked like `return( ! isset($contents) || ! $contents ? array() : $contents);` Which might make a little more sense why it was that way, I just neglected to reposition the rest when I changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few different questions you ask, so I'll try to address them all.

Missed branch predictions: Unless you're coding in C or assembly, don't worry about this.  In PHP, you're so far from the hardware that thinking about branch predictions isn't going to help you.  Either way, this would be a very-micro optimization, especially in a function that does extensive string parsing to begin with.

> Is there any other reason not to use this? Wikipedia seems to think so, but only in reference to C. I know PHP is written in C, so that is definitely pertinent information.

PHP likely parses it to a different execution structure.  Unless you're planning on running this function millions of times, or you know it's a bottleneck, I wouldn't worry about it.  In 2012, I find it very unlikely that using an `or` to short circuit would cause even a billionth of a second difference.

As for the formatting, I find `$a or $b` rather ugly.  My mind doesn't comprehend the short circuiting the same it sees it in an if clause.

```
if (a() || b())
```

Is perfectly clear to my mind that b() will execute only if a() does not evaluate to true.

However:

```
return a() or b();
```

Doesn't have the same clarity to me.

That's obviously just an opinion, but I'll offer two alternatives as to how I might write it (which are, in my opinion, a very tiny bit clearer):

```
function load($file) {
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        touch($file);
        return array();
    }

    $raw = file_get_contents($file);

    $contents = json_decode($raw, true);

    if (is_array($contents)) {
        return $contents;
    } else {
        return array();
    }

}
```

If you don't care if the file actually gets created, you could take it a step farther:

```
function load($file) {

    $raw = file_get_contents($file);

    if ($raw !== false) {
        $contents = json_decode($raw, true);
        if ($contents !== null) {
            return $contents;
        }
    }

    return array();

}
```

I guess really these code snippets come down to personal preference.  The second snippet is likely the one I would go with.  The critical paths could be a bit clearer in it, but I feel like it maintains brevity without sacrificing comprehensibility.

Edit: If you're a 1-return-per-function type person, the following might be a bit more preferable:

```
function load($file) {

    $contents = array();

    $raw = file_get_contents($file);

    if ($raw !== false) {
        $contents = json_decode($raw, true);
        if ($contents === null) {
            $contents = array();
        }
    }

    return $contents;

}
```

Comment: @Madbreaks I was expecting someone to say that.  I find it much clearer if you bail out on error cases early.  Why bother handling errors through the rest of the function?  And, you can glance at it and immediately see what the function checks at the top.  (Though neither of my offered alternatives make a particularly good case for this.)

Comment: I'm actually in agreement with Madbreaks. I think one point of exit is better than many. Much how many people only like one point of entry. Its the same concept. Not having to keep track of multiple returns means I can more easily control what exits the function and how I process it. Thank you for your answer. Would changing it to `return a() || b()` make more sense to you? Both are valid and I also prefer the later, I was only using `or` to keep with previous examples.

Comment: I don't think it's the `or` rather than `||` that strikes me as odd.  I don't know.  For some reason using the value of a short circuited expression looks odd to me.  Like I said in the answer, it's probably just me with that oddity, though.  And it comes down to personal preference, but as someone who used to always use 1 return statement, I believe that functions really can be written more cleanly with multiple.

Comment: @showerhead Also, with the "entry point" and "exit point" terminology...  That actually is a large part of why people have the one return statement mentality.  In machine code, there aren't actually 'functions' so much as you just know the address to jump to.  The "one entry" ideology stems from the days of assembly coding when it considered very bad form to jump into the middle of a function.  (Doesn't really affect anything in the context of this question, but I just think it's interesting.)

Comment: There is much for me to think about. I will let this question stew for a little longer to see if there is any more activity, otherwise I will award you the answer tomorrow. Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: I did not know that about the "entry point" and "exit point". I just remembered reading it in an article some time ago and liked the ideas it cultivated so I adopted it. Haven't forced the issue with the entry point so much as I'm usually more interested in what I do with the data than where it comes from.

Comment: @showerhead In the original sense of the term, functions in high level languages do not have more than one entry point (or any sense I can think of).  And hopefully someone will come along and answer the question in more technical way than my opinionated ramblings.  I'm not sure if my answer really deserves to be accepted haha.

Comment: If by entry points you mean methods.  Methods do not have more than 1 entry point though :).

Answer (score 1):

Condensing your code into the minimalistic lines possible you can get it isnt always the best method, as usually compacting code looks pretty cool however is usually hard to read. If you have any doubts about your code and the readability, i'd suggest you add some standard comments into your code so any person can understand the code from your comments alone.

In terms of best practice, thats a matter of opinion, and if you are happy with it then go with it, you can always revisit the code later on down the projects life if needs be

Comment: Yes I know, and I usually do add comments if I wish to clarify a point. I do like to ensure my code is still legible, which is why I don't always condense it, only if I think it will be easily understood.

Answer (score 0):

I do like short-circuit declarations as it a way to do one-line variables check.

I prefer:

```
isset($value) or $value = 0;
```

Rather than:

```
if (!isset($value)) {
  $value = 0;
}
```

---

But I haven't used it directly in returns and this post made want to try.

And sadly, it does not work properly, at least for me:

```
return $data[$key] or $data[1];
```

Will return the value 1 in all cases while I'm expecting an array.

The following works smoothly:

```
// Make sure $key is valid.
$data[$key] or $key = 1;

return $data[$key];
```

But I'm surprised PHP is not throwing any error when $key doesn't exist in $data.